# Apple Open Source and CocoaTouch Classes?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, open-source

I just want to verify this to ensure I'm not making a dumb mistake.

Does Apple offer any of its CocoaTouch classes for Open Source? I checked [opensource.apple.com](http://opensource.apple.com), and did not see any. http://www.google.com/#q=nsuuid+site:opensource.apple.com.

I'm interested in the NSUUID class for iOS 5 and lesser (its available in iOS 6) and would be happy to copy/paste it rather than roll it myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No this will not be open source.

But you don't need to roll your own as you can just drop down to using [CFUUIDRef](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFUUIDRef/Reference/reference.html)